# How to deal with 3 column recordset in Google Charts?

Tags: charts, google-visualization, aggregate, bar-chart

I have a MySQL recordset like:

```
Date;Customer;Turnover
2016-03-01;Cust1;120
2016-03-01;Cust2;120
2016-04-01;Cust1;130
2016-04-01;Cust2;125
2016-05-01;Cust1;135
2016-05-01;Cust2;110
```

My goal is to have a stacked bar chart with Year/Month on the x-axis (type of date so I can use date filters), and customer values stacked on top of each other. In addition I need to filter the customers I want to hide from the display.

I've been trying to group/aggregate the data, also played with dashboard filter controls, but I haven't made a breakthrough yet so I was hoping someone might give me a hint on where to start with this.

Comment: what part do you need help with, can you share any of the code you _spent hours trying_? -- [see this example -- stacked-column-charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#stacked-column-charts)

Comment: Hi WhiteHat! I've got nothing conclusive, just trying different approaches. So my first challenge would be to convert from "single column" data (Cust1, Cust2... under eachother) to series-aware DataTable - I haven't managed to achieve that. I could have the MySQL Procedure produce the output with Customers as columns, but I'd like to keep the DataTable flat if possible.

Comment: Dirty code here (I want to be able to aggregate by user-id and customer-id and be able to stack and hide/show the series in the bar chart):
https://jsfiddle.net/ye9d2pyh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to display the date on the x-axis, you need a column for each customer

1. Group the data by Date, Customer
2. Sort grouped data by Date, Customer
3. Get unique Customer Id's
4. Build new table with column for each Customer

see example, taken from the provided fiddle...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawVisualization,
  packages:['corechart', 'table', 'controls']
});

function drawVisualization() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    cols: [
      {id: 'dat_ym', label: 'Start Date', type: 'date'},
      {id: 'user-id', label: 'User-Id', type: 'string'},
      {id: 'customer-id', label: 'Customer-Id', type: 'string'},
      {id: 's_minutes', label: 'minutes', type: 'number'}
    ],
    rows: [
      {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 01, 01')}, {v: '44836'}, {v: '67205'}, {v: 1122} ]},
      {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 01, 01')}, {v: '86495'}, {v: '67205'}, {v: 332} ]},
      {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 01, 01')}, {v: '44836'}, {v: '228626'}, {v: 0} ]},
      {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 01, 01')}, {v: '86495'}, {v: '228626'}, {v: 334} ]},
      {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 02, 01')}, {v: '44836'}, {v: '67205'}, {v: 554} ]},
      {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 02, 01')}, {v: '86495'}, {v: '67205'}, {v: 0} ]},
      {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 02, 01')}, {v: '44836'}, {v: '228626'}, {v: 0} ]},
      {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 02, 01')}, {v: '86495'}, {v: '228626'}, {v: 544} ]},
    ]
  });

  // group data by date, customer
  var grouped_data = google.visualization.data.group(
    data,
    [0, 2],
    [
      {'column': 3, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}
    ]
  );

  // sort grouped data
  grouped_data.sort([{column: 0},{column: 1}]);

  // get unique customers
  var custGroup = google.visualization.data.group(
    data,
    [2]
  );

  // build customer data table
  var custData = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    cols: [
      {id: 'dat_ym', label: 'Start Date', type: 'date'},
    ]
  });

  // add column for each customer
  for (var i = 0; i < custGroup.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    custData.addColumn(
      {label: custGroup.getValue(i, 0), type: 'number'}
    );
  }

  // add rows for each date
  var rowDate;
  var rowIndex;
  for (var i = 0; i < grouped_data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    // add row when date changes
    if (rowDate !== grouped_data.getValue(i, 0).getTime()) {
      rowDate = grouped_data.getValue(i, 0).getTime();
      rowIndex = custData.addRow();
      custData.setValue(rowIndex, 0, new Date(rowDate));
    }

    // find customer column
    for (var x = 1; x < custData.getNumberOfColumns(); x++) {
      if (custData.getColumnLabel(x) === grouped_data.getValue(i, 1)) {
        custData.setValue(rowIndex, x, grouped_data.getValue(i, 2));
      }
    }
  }

  var options = {
    hAxis: {title: '', textStyle: { fontSize: '13' }, textPosition: 'in'},
    vAxis: {title: '', textStyle: { fontSize: '10' }},
    seriesType: 'bars',
    legend: {position: 'top', textStyle: {color: 'black', fontSize: 14}},
    isStacked: true
  };

  var tableTE = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div_te'));
  tableTE.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, frozenColumns: 1, width: '100%', height: '300'});

  var tableTEAgg = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div_teagg'));
  tableTEAgg.draw(custData, {showRowNumber: true, frozenColumns: 1, width: '100%', height: '300'});

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(custData, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table_div_te"></div>
<div id="table_div_teagg"></div>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 1600px; height: 300px;"></div>
```